# How to add a readonly email to Forgot password

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

My custom policiy for forgot password is based on this documentation: [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy)

how can I add to the 3rd page before password label, a label and an input text for readonly email?

Answer (score 0):

To add labels, you need [JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-and-page-layout?pivots=b2c-custom-policy).

For "readonlyEmail" look at this [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/af7f3532c44fac48eee4ffa176fb2b349818ebd0/policies/mfa-email-or-phone).

You'll see it copies it from "email".

Then in "LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId". set "readonlyEmail" as an input and output claim.